# NW.js and WebStorm

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm, nw.js

I am trying to get NW.js to work well with WebStorm. I have it so that It runs the nw.js project. However, WebStorm seems completely unable to resolve any of the dependencies such as `nw.Menu()`.

The documentation says that nw.gui does not require you to require or in my case import. I can not seem to find anything on how to fix this online. So how do I get WebStorm to resolve these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too sure about all this myself, but here is how I do it anyway:

1. Go to settings (ctrl-alt-s), Languages & Frameworks, Libraries.
2. Click download. Change dropdown from `Official libraries` to `Typescript community stubs`.
3. Find `node-webkit`. This is the old name for nw.js. There is no stub for nw.js yet that I know of. Download and install.
4. This is usually enough for other libraries, but for some reason I must fix the scopes for it to work with nw.js.  Therefore click `manage scopes`.
5. Choose your project root directory, and click on the space to the right of the directory below `Library`. Make sure `node-webkit` is checked.

With that done I was able to resolve dependencies and get code completions for nw.js.  It might be old though but at least it's something.

[image]